# Getting the word out - music blogs and press

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

The best way to get new users to our site is through word of mouth. Therefore, if we can reach people who have big mouths (i.e., wide readership :), more people will know who we are and why we're awesome.

I'd like to compile a list of music bloggers and journalists that you all think would be good to expose to this site.

**Note:** This list is not a "who can I spam with press releases?" type list. Ideally, these people would explore the site, use it a little, and if they like us, do some sort of review / publicity. And hopefully continue to be active users; we're looking for people who are experts in this area AND have some sort of following / klout in the community. I encourage each of you to promote the site whenever you can, to whomever you can - I will not provide a form letter because we at Stack Exchange believe in honest-to-goodness one-on-one interaction. :)

Although someone posted a [great form letter over on Cooking.SE](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196/get-the-word-out-food-blogs-and-press) a long time ago...

I think it would be great to have all these bloggers and journalists listed in one place that can be curated collectively and continually.

So...who do you think are good people to contact to help spread the word about music.SE and attract new users?

Answer (score 2):

[The Guild of International Songwriters & Composers](http://www.songwriters-guild.co.uk/contact.htm), although I received no answer when I contacted them about this.

Comment: Thank you! This looks like a great organization for us to partner with. I'll try to get in touch with them as well.

Answer (score 2):

In the UK, the [Musician's Union](http://www.musiciansunion.org.uk/) would be a useful one - their regular paper news magazine and online bulletins are widely circulated.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! I'll contact them.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe by approaching the various Music Colleges (a leaflet bluetak'd to a board or an Ad in a college newspaper) -> UK: http://www.rma.ac.uk/resources/he-departments.asp

Also http://www.rma.ac.uk/publications/

Comment: Thanks! On my list to reach out to.

Answer (score 1):

### [Peter Kirn's Create Digital Music site](http://createdigitalmusic.com/)

Everybody into electronic music and music technology reads it. 
And I know Peter and can make an introduction for you.